# Как реализовать на лендинге возможность выбора и оплаты НЕСКОЛЬКИХ товаров?

Tags: html, css

Есть сайт. 
Там есть два товара. Сейчас подключена(но, видимо, не настроена) платёжная система walletone.
Задача - сделать так, чтобы клиент мог выбрать кол-во, метод оплаты, способ доставки(чтобы такие поля в форме были). Что-то типа он нажимает купить и попадает на отдельную страницу или появляется модальное окно с такими полями.

Сейчас по кнопке купить клиента перекидывает сразу на страницу оплаты одного товара с ценой(типа интеграция с платёжной системой).
Как это лучше реализовать? Создать отдельную страницу(модальное окно)? Можно ли легко, не особо дружа с PHP, настроить это, может быть, из самой платёжной системы? И как?)

Comment: список тегов я бы расширил. Ну обычно под такие задачи добавляется функционал "корзины" отдельной страницей или попапом - дело десятое, главное что бы товары складировались куда-то (жалательно, что бы это отображалось где-то конечно, но не обязательно), а при нажатии "перейти к покупке/оплате" цены суммировались. Тут как минимум нужны познания в бекенде/бд/js. Как минимум 1 шаг ещё пропущен: куда отправлять. Сначала надо собрать данные куда высылать, перед тем как просить оплату - это логично.

Comment: Конечно, можно. Просто нанимаете фрилансера, платите ему денег и все - самим вообще знать ничего не обязательно. а если по делу - то нужен код